# "Start Tor Browser" shortcut don't respond when I double click it on my windows 10

Tags: windows

I downloaded and reinstalled Tor browser many times to make it work but it doesn't.

Once the installation is complete, I click Finish to launch Tor Browser's wizard, but nothing happens. Then I go to my Desktop and double click on the "Start Tor Browser" shortcut and nothing happens.

I am using Windows 10. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check your anti-virus, and windows application event logs for anything relating to `firefox.exe` and `tor.exe` and let us know what the logs say if you find any. You should also try disabling or uninstalling `Trusteer Rapport` if you have it.

Comment: Perfect. It was the Trusteer Rapport the problem. Thank you very much.